# csv file to phpmyadmin import error

Tags: microsoft-excel, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

here is the pattern of my csv file

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   col1    |   col2   |           |   col4   |            |  
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   col1    |   col2   |           |   col4   |            |   
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   col1    |   col2   |           |   col4   |            |   
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   col1    |   col2   |           |   col4   |            |   
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   col1    |   col2   |           |   col4   |            |   
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   col1    |   col2   |           |   col4   |            |  
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

i have something like this, empty columns on the table in .csv file in excel 2010.
empty column has default data set in phpmyadmin.
while importing it's throwing **Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1.**

how can i solve this?

thanks in advance.!

**Edit:**

here is the sample of my csv file

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   9    |   6   |           |   Yes, Capacitive   |   3.5 Inches   |      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   9    |   6   |           |   Yes, Capacitive   |   4.5 Inches   |      |  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   9    |   6   |           |   Yes, Capacitive   |   4.5 Inches   |      |   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   9    |   6   |           |   Yes, Capacitive   |   3.5 Inches   |      |   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   9    |   6   |           |   Yes, Capacitive   |   4.5 Inches   |      |  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   9    |   6   |           |   Yes, Capacitive   |    4 Inches    |      | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you checked that you don't have any unintended newline either before or around the first line? If you open the CSV file in a text editor, and then set the text editor to show invisibles such as white space, tabs etc. 

Have you also checked the correct deliminator and file format in the import settings?

Comment: @olovholm yeah i have checked i dont have any. i have opened with notepad and i found something like few cells doesn't have quotes enclosed with and few have enclosed.

Comment: @olovholm i cant manually include quotes which doesn't have, what could be a solution as i have lot of data.

Comment: OK, are you loading a lot of data? You could improve the structure by filling in the quotes. You can also, probably, select an option which ignores the quotes and then remove them with SQL once loaded or strip the quotes before loading if you don't need them. If the set is huge, and you can accept some losses, but not any alterations most load in tools have a setting to drop not successful rows as well. I've done this a couple of times when tables where 1 mill plus rows and a few rows with faults.

Comment: @olovholm how can i fill in the quotes, can u please elaborate if u dont mind !!

Comment: Could you please provide some sample rows with the quotes, so I can see how the format is?

Comment: @olovholm i have edited the question.

Comment: u want it with delimiters??

Comment: Just a clarification: The dotted lines between the lines in your sample are not there in the file you try to load?

Comment: they are empty cells which will b filled later, is that possible??

Comment: If you could just add a couple of lines from your CSV which covers a couple of normal lines, and a couple of problematic lines that would be great. Please do not alter the structure of the CSV file (except adding a newline if that is not done automatically).

Comment: i il copy couple of lines from notepad

Comment: u can see an empy cell before nd after iphone, is that makng a problm??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13265/discussion-between-olovholm-and-stacky)

Answer (score 1):

The formatting is the problem in this case. The reason you get an import error is that the parser cannot understand the data as a structured comma separated list. This problem is the result of two parts

- Quoting is not consistent. Some elements are opened with quote, but not closed, hence the quote is expanded into the new field
- The delimeter is existing also in the data. When you have a comma seperator and a comma is used in the text variable and the quotes are not consistent then the parser may mistake a textual commma for a structural comma.

Two suggestions to solve the problem:

- Clean up the quotation marks: all opening quotation marks must have a corresponding closing quotation marks.
- Use a delimiter which cannot be found in the data. This way the parser will not confuse the data with the structure of the CSV.

Comment: okay seems legit, ill try it now !!

Answer (score 0):

All that i did is

1. Imported the file.
2. selected the Format to **CSV using load data**
3. Replaced **Columns separated with: to comma(,)**
4. then press GO.

DONE